# set different sized text in one textview in adapter

Tags: android

```
        String datetime1=rowItem.getDatetime();
        SpannableString spannabledatetime1 = new SpannableString(datetime1);
        spannabledatetime1.setSpan(
            new RelativeSizeSpan(dimen.txtsize1), 
            0,
            datetime1.length(), 
            0);
        spannabledatetime1.setSpan(
            new ForegroundColorSpan(color.green), 
            0,datetime1.length(), 
            0);
        holder.txtLeftMsg.setText(rowItem.getMsg()+"\n"+spannabledatetime1);
```

I want date time in my custom `txtsize1` and my custom color green. and `rowItem.getMsg()` as usual i get it from xml file.  this code is written in adapter class.

Comment: Unclear question. What do you want? "set different sized text" or "date time and custom color green and getMsg()"...

Comment: actually i got msg from rowItem.getMsg() and date from rowItem.getDate() in adapter class . i want to setText both msg and data in one textview. but in different size and color. I hope u understand now...............i want two set two text data in one TextView in different size and color.

Answer (score -1):

```
 String datetime1=rowItem.getMsg() +"\n"+ rowItem.getDatetime();
        SpannableString spannabledatetime1=  new SpannableString(datetime1);
        spannabledatetime1.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(dimen.txtsize1), rowItem.getMsg(),datetime1.length(), 0);
        spannabledatetime1.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(color.green), rowItem.getMsg(), datetime1.length(), 0);
        holder.txtLeftMsg.setText(spannabledatetime1);
```

Comment: You should not post code-only answers. Add some explanation of what you are doing.